# issue with updating a mysql database column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hi I am having trouble updating my mysql table when I use the follow sql:

```
if(isset($_POST['submitFeedback'])){
      $error = array();
      $success = array();
      $url = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
      $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['ad_id']);
      $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['email']);
      $voted = '1';
      if(!isset($_POST['userFeedback'])){
         $error[] = 'Please select some feedback';
      }else{
         if(isset($_POST['subComment'])){
           $comment = strtolower(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['userFeedback']));
           $subComment = strtolower(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['subComment']));

           $insertIntoBuyerFeedback = mysql_query("UPDATE buyer_feedback SET
                    seller_vote='$voted', seller_comment='$comment',
                    seller_sub_comment='$subComment',
                WHERE ad_id='$id' AND buyer_email='$email'") or die(mysql_error());
           $success[] = 'Thank you for your feedback!';
         }
      }
   }
```

I get the following error from the browser

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE ad_id='5' AND buyer_email='test@test.com'' at line 1
```

Which makes no sense to me considering that I have escaped the strings in question. Even the strings before those in question

Comment: Superfluous comma here: `...ller_sub_comment='$subComment',`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of the extra comma after your last update column (seller_sub_comment).

```
"UPDATE buyer_feedback 
SET seller_vote='$voted',seller_comment='$comment',seller_sub_comment='$subComment'
WHERE ad_id='$id' AND buyer_email='$email'"
```

Comment: By the way, I'd suggest you use `$comment = mysql_real_escape_string(strtolower($_POST['userFeedback']));` instead of `$comment = strtolower(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['userFeedback']));` just in case.

Comment: Why should that make a difference?

Comment: lol i swear i tried that